# Yield function not fetching the complete data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, generator, yield

I have an excel with multiple sheets, i have to iterate through all the sheets and pass the contents of the sheet through the yield function.

```
    sheetnames = xls.sheetnames
    for s in sheetnames:
        result = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name=s)
        count_row = result.shape[0]
        for i in range(count_row):
            r = result.iloc[i]
            yield r
```

here sheetnames fetches the list of sheets, i would want to iterate through each sheet and get the row values. Now iam getting only the values of the first sheet and not the sheets after that, i.e; the yield is not working for the outer for loop of sheets. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: because the generator gets exhausted in the first sheet. why not just `yield result`, looping over rows is an overkill here since you are anyways taking all the rows.

Comment: I had to send each row as input, so had to had to iterate with row count but this can be managed in the main function once i get everything through yield. Your solution works perfect!!